# Fedora 14 root missing capability

Tags: kernel, capabilities

I am trying to run a process that performs a clone() operation using a set of flags (CLONE_NEWIPC, CLONE_NEWNET, ...) that require CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability.

This should not be a problem since I am running the process as root, but for some reason, it works on a debian wheezy 3.2.0 but not on a fedora 14 2.6.32. It throws an EPERM error which according to the CLONE(2) man page, means it was run by "an unprivileged process (process without CAP_SYS_ADMIN)". Again, everything is running as root.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Hard to know, could be a problem with selinux. At any rate, Fedora 14 is way beyond end of life so support will be minimal at best. If the problem persists with a newer version of Fedora, post back.

Comment: Also we need more information about "a process that ..."

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with Fedora 14 at the moment. The process is GUIX, but anyway I created a small app that does only the cloning function to isolate the issue and I have the same behavior.

Comment: Did you disable selinux ?

Comment: selinux is not installed